# Swift UILabel not setting correct y value

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've confirmed, that the value given to "addLabel" function, is changing, but when printing out "label.frame.origin.y", it's always showing 0. At the moment, the code looks pretty bad, because I've been struggling with this issue for a while now. Any ideas?

```
    var newY: Int = 8
    var mainViewNewHeight: Int = 251

    func setContentFromList(content: [String], target: UIView, targetHeight: NSLayoutConstraint) {
        newY = 8
        var bullet:UILabel!
        let width = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - 84
        let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)
        for item in content {
            bullet = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: newY, width: 7, height: 17))
            bullet.text = "•"
            bullet.textColor = UIColor( red: 183/255, green: 110/255, blue:121/255, alpha: 1.0 )
            bullet.font = bullet.font.withSize(18)
            let a = CGFloat(newY)
            print(a) // Correct
            addLabel(y: a, text: item, font: font!, width: CGFloat(width), target: target)
            target.addSubview(bullet)
        }
        mainViewNewHeight += newY
        targetHeight.constant = CGFloat(newY)
    }
```

And this is the "addLabel" function:

```
    func addLabel(y: CGFloat, text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat, target: UIView) {
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: y, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        print("Label y:", label.frame.origin.y) // Invalid (0.0)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        newY += Int(label.frame.height)

        target.addSubview(label)
    }
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious, but the current labels stack on each other. I need them to be under each other.

Comment: Do not use "sizeToFit" with autolayout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` remove `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` and replace it with an `integer value` and you´ll see that your code will work.

So basically:

```
let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: y, width: width, height: 20))
```

Print out:

```
20.0
Label y: 20.0
41.0
Label y: 41.0
62.0
Label y: 62.0
83.0
Label y: 83.0
```